# Possible values for RichTextMode field

Tags: site-column

What are the possible values that I can use on the "RichTextMode" field supported by SharePoint when creating a custom Site Column.  I believe they are "Compatible" and "FullHTML", however I've seen others being used as well.

Answer (score 13):

They are documented [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.sprichtextmode.aspx)

[image]